# how i could make html2pdf.js return pdf to be a blob and send it for array buffer

Tags: blob, html2pdf, arraybuffer

I have been working with `html2pdf.js` library to convert the HTML content to PDF and add my own custom header and footer on each page while converting. This actually works for me, but I couldn't pass the output PDF to the arraybuffer as it gives me the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.

All I was trying to do is create custom pages from html content using `html2pdf.js` library then pass it to the arraybuffer as a blob. here is the code

```js
async postArrayBufferByServerRelativeUrl(
    content,
    serverRelativeUrl,
    fileName
  ) {
    const filePromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const url: string =
        this.webUrl +
        "/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" +
        serverRelativeUrl +
        "')/files/add(url='" +
        fileName +
        "',overwrite=true)";
      const fetchedDigest = await this.getFormDigest();
      const formDigestValue =
        fetchedDigest.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;

      var opt = {
        margin: 1,
        filename: fileName,
        image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: {
          scale: 2,
          logging: true,
          dpi: 192,
          letterRendering: true,
        },
        jsPDF: {
          unit: "in",
          format: "a4",
          orientation: "portrait",
          putOnlyUsedFonts: true,
          floatPrecision: 16, // or "smart", default is 16
        },
      };

      let pdfBlob = new Blob(
        await html2pdf()
          .from(content)
          .set(opt)
          .toCanvas()
          .toPdf()
          .get("pdf")
          .then((pdf) => {
            var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
            for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
              pdf.setPage(i);
              pdf.setFontSize(10);
              pdf.setTextColor(200);

              pdf.text(
                "Page " + i + " of " + totalPages,
                pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() / 2.3,
                pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 2
              );
            }
            console.log(pdf);
          })
          .output(Blob)
          .then((pdf) => {
            return pdf;
          })
      );
      

      var arrayBuffer;
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function () {
        arrayBuffer = this.result;
        $.ajax({
          url,
          type: "POST",
          data: arrayBuffer,
          processData: false,
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": formDigestValue,
          },
          success: function (data) {
            resolve(data);
          },
          error: function (error) {
            reject(error.message);
          },
        });
      };
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(pdfBlob);
    });

    return await filePromise;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.output(Blob)` should be `.output("blob")`